# Replace all in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I replace all occurences of "http://localhost" in a string in javascript?

I have `res=res.replace(/^http\:\/\/localhost, url);`, but it does not work. How do I fix it?

`url` is a variable and but "localhost" is a string.

**UPDATE:**

With the solutions below, I still get: `ReferenceError: localhost is not defined`. What am I missing?

**UPDATE 2:**

This is the (Perl) code that inserts the JS on the page:

```
$form .=  qq|<script>res='$doc'; loc=document.location.href; url=loc.substring(0,loc.indexOf(":8080")); res=res.replace(/http\:\/\/localhost/g, url); document.location='data:text/html;charset:utf-8,' + res; </script>|;
```

Comment: The statement is not completed.

Comment: @Dere0405 I believe I completed it now.

Comment: Well if you get that with the solutions below, than you copied something wrong.

Comment: which does not match what they have below... And that error you state should not come from that code.

Comment: A String is not a RegExp.

Answer (score 0):

```
res=res.replace(/http\:\/\/localhost/g, url);
```

'g' indicates to replace all.

Comment: I get: `ReferenceError: localhost is not defined`

Comment: Note that the ^ at the start of the regex ensures it will only match once anyway (at the start of the string).

Answer (score 0):

use /g to replace every occurrence in your string

Something like this

```
str = str.replace(/http:\/\/localhost/g,'');
```

Comment: I get: `ReferenceError: localhost is not defined`. Obviously I don't have a variable `localhost`.

Comment: @kepj There's no variable `localhost` in the code. It's in a regexp, it's not a variable.

Comment: @Barmar The console complains that I have no variable `localhost`. I know I don't have one. I don't understand why it complains!

Comment: Can you post more of your code ?

Comment: @SenthilKumarM Yes, I have updated the question.

Comment: @SenthilKumarM I inadvertently copied an incorrect line. Fixed now.

Comment: Cheers !!! Hope it was useful ..

Comment: @SenthilKumarM No, I meant I copied the wrong line from my code to "Update 2".